# How to minimize all windows on a particular monitor in XFce?

Tags: xfce, window-management

I need to minimize all windows on a specific monitor (monitor0) from the command line. A specific script is run, and it will call for all windows on that screen to close. The effect is the same as hitting the "Show Desktop" button in the panel.

Is there a way to minimize all open windows on a specific monitor from the command line in XFce?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
wmctrl -s <monitor ID> -k on
```

you have to install wmctrl first hope you know how to do it.